# Circular progress bar (border)

Tags: html, css, sass

I found [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/1438386-iOS7-longtouch-sharing-concept) on dribbble.

Is it possible to create this circular progress bar (where the progress bar is the outer border of the circle) in the first ~3 seconds of the gif?

So far, I have the circle itself without any animation on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44ch0p8u/7/)

How would I go on from here?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-color: #3a88cd;
  padding: 60px;
}

.circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This looks like toooooooooo huge task for answering in Stack Overflow. You need to go a looooooong way from here.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I'm not trying to recreate everything that you see in that dribbble gif. All I want to recreate is that progress bar that progresses around the white circle.

Comment: Ah... I just saw it. I don't think it is possible... We need to use SVG. Lemme try...

Comment: [Here's something](http://web.archive.org/web/20160514035222/http://blog.invatechs.com/round_progress_bar_with_html5_css3_and_javascript), and [here](http://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-circular-percentage-bar/).

Comment: @user7332813 I submitted a JSFiddle as an answer of one way to do this with CSS, based on your Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was fun. Had some time to kill, so I took this as a challenge and ran with it. Coded in SCSS on JSFiddle. I included some variables on top of the SCSS to tweak everything. The jQuery is only there for the click event to add a class.

https://jsfiddle.net/44ch0p8u/11/

And non-Sass version to see it live here:

```js
$('.circle').on('click', function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $this.removeClass('animate');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.addClass('animate');
  }, 50)
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3a88cd;
  padding: 60px;
}
.circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle-right:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.circle-right:after {
  content: '';
  background: #3a88cd;
  border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.circle.animate .circle-right:after {
  animation: circle-half 1s forwards ease-in;
}
.circle-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.circle-left:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.circle-left:after {
  content: '';
  background: #3a88cd;
  border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.circle.animate .circle-left:after {
  animation: circle-half 1s 1s forwards ease-out;
}
.circle-inner {
  background: #3a88cd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.circle-inner:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
}
@keyframes circle-half {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.1);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle-inner"></div>
  <div class="circle-left"></div>
  <div class="circle-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass a % in the `style`, like 50%, and the progress bar would go to 50%?